# Change a hidden input's value with jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, input, hidden, required

I have some hidden input values that I would like to have be changed to a certain value once a user clicks on a link.

Comment: Why do you want to require a hidden input?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "choose a value for not selected" - not selected in your example is a link/list element, not a form field.

Comment: can you please try to explain you need better ? give some time to rewrite your problem in a way to be clear. remember you need to help us understand that we can help you solve your problem

Comment: You should be able to change an element's attributes whether hidden or not. What problem are you encountering?

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.someLink').click(function(){
    $('.someHiddenInput').val('new value');
});
```

I think this is what you mean.

HTML would look something like:

```
<a href="#" class="someLink">click me to change value</a>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenVal" class="someHiddenInput" value="old value" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="hidden" id="txtTextHdn" name="txtTextHdn" value="Y" />
<a href="#" id="testLink">Click Me!</a>

$("#testLink").click(function () {
    alert($("#txtTextHdn").val());
    $("#txtTextHdn").val('X');
    alert($("#txtTextHdn").val());
})
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(*link selector*).click(function(){
    $(*hidden selector*).val();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UbScn/