# <Input type="button>, How can I know when are they active?

Tags: php, html, input

I have this HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <input type="button" name="meat" class="btn btn-default active" value="Both">
     <input type="button" name="meat" class="btn btn-default" value="Red">
     <input type="button" name="meat" class="btn btn-default" value="White">
     <input type="button" name="meat" class="btn btn-default" value="None">
</div>
```

This with addition os some css gives this resoult:

[image: button group for input]

I use this code to only allow one active:

```
 $(".btn-group > .btn").click(function(){
     $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
 });
```

But it is just visual, and when I try to input vía php POST (within a form) I don't get nothing.

If i change to type=radio, the PHP works fine, but it is uglier.

¿Any magical idea to make it work keeping it fancy?

The php code for testing is:

```
<html>
<body>

MegaUltraTest <?php echo ($_POST["meat"]); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: _"If i change to type=radio, the PHP works fine, but it is uglier."_ So style the radio buttons to work like the buttons you have above. It looks like you're using Bootstrap, so use Bootstrap's styles.

Comment: you can always add the button classes to your radios

Comment: Use an `<input type="hidden" id="meat" name="meat"/>` and set it's value within the `onclick` event of your buttons. Its value will be transmitted when you POST the page.

Comment: I'm trying with the radio styling, seems to be an easy solution, I feel stupid now XD Thx

Answer (score 1):

> These buttons inside 'btn-group' div, aren't doing anything useful, apart from just displaying some buttons on the screen. They are not aware of any 'selected' property (in order for the selected value to be submitted).
>
> Buttons are not meant to act like radio buttons, checkboxes etc. Their purpose is to perform an action when they are clicked.
>
> So what i recomend is to forget about button group and just add checkboxes. If you are concerned about the styling, just add this very useful library (http://icheck.fronteed.com/). I think line skin will be great for you.
>
> If you really want these buttons, you should write some js code (preferably jquery) and on the click event, store the selected value(s) in a hidden input that will get submitted. See here: Change a hidden input's value with jquery/javascript

Source : [Send Bootstrap Button-Group value in a form with Get or Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755901/send-bootstrap-button-group-value-in-a-form-with-get-or-post)
by nkwinder

Comment: Thanks, I've been searching for hours :D

Comment: Your welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `$_POST['meat']` exists and check if the value is equal to it:
Implement it like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <input type="button" name="meat" class="btn btn-default <?= isset($_POST['meat']) && $_POST['meat'] === 'Both' ? 'active' : ''; ?>" value="Both">
     <input type="button" name="meat" class="btn btn-default" value="Red">
     <input type="button" name="meat" class="btn btn-default" value="White">
     <input type="button" name="meat" class="btn btn-default" value="None">
</div>
```