# POST button values not going through with backend

Tags: php, html

So i have this script that supposed to pass values of buttons on the backend

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   $monday_hours = $_POST['monday_hours'];
   echo $monday_hours;                                                
}
?>
```

Here is the html code.

```
<div class = "mon-btn-group">
  <form method="post"> 
    <button type = "button" name = "monday_hours" value = "1_hour">1</button>
    <button type = "button" name = "monday_hours" value = "2_hours">2</button>
    <button type = "button" name = "monday_hours" value = "3_hours">3</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

So my question is without changing the type is it possible for this group of buttons values to be caught in the backend if they all have the same name like radio buttons or checkboxes?

It echos the value if i remove the type = "button" but I dont want that since i read that buttons have submit as their default behaviour.

> [Send Bootstrap Button-Group value in a form with Get or Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755901/send-bootstrap-button-group-value-in-a-form-with-get-or-post)

EDIT: Nevermind found this post, thanks guys sorry, its my first time posting.

Comment: You cannot have multiple buttons with the same name, if you do so, only the last button will be submitted.

Comment: post the full form code, are you using ,method="post"?

Comment: this question is way too unclear. What does this function do `test_input()` and where is the form tags? Plus, the id's suggests JS; are you using JS?

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons should have unique names. They should also be wrapped in a form with the method set to POST.

```
<button type = "button" id = "m1" name = "monday_hours_1" value = "1_hour">1</button>
<button type = "button" id = "m2" name = "monday_hours_2" value = "2_hours">2</button>
<button type = "button" id = "m3" name = "monday_hours_3" value = "3_hours">3</button>
```

Comment: oh so you cant do button groups like radip buttons or checkboxes on a regular button element?

Comment: No. An alternative approach is to use a radio button group and submit the form when changed. 

If you insist on using buttons, add an onclick event/ function that updates the value of a textbox (hidden maybe) then submit the form.

Comment: Thanks, ill most likely do the hidden textbox as a quick fix, Thanks again good sir.